# Remotely reboot tomcat

Tags: centos, tomcat, redhat, ant

I am trying to reboot my tomcat version 5 on a centos server from my dev box.  I can login as a normal user(not root) but I need to be able to reboot the service.  Is there a config file that I can modify or a group my my user needs to be in to be able to restart the tomcat5 service?

**EDIT**: I will be running this task in Ant, and sudo will not work for this as Ant does not give you a virtual terminal.

**EDIT**: here is the error when I try to restart tomcat as root via ant.

```
ssh root@server.com /sbin/service tomcat5 restart

restartTomcat:
 [exec] Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

This is running as root,which has ssh privileges.  The command as is works fine.

**EDIT**

```
vi /etc/sudoers (EDIT: please use visudo instead)
comment out: #Default requiretty
```

This fixes the tty item.  Now it works as the normal user.

Here is my ant target

```
<target name="restartTomcat">
  <exec executable="/usr/bin/ssh">
    <arg line="user@server.com sudo /sbin/service tomcat5 restart"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Can you connect in as the user that tomcat is running as? (which is the 'tomcat' user on my machines) or maybe su to them?

Comment: It's not good practice to give application users shell access - stick to sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having issues using sudo and you get a message like this:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Then you should comment out:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

Inside `/etc/sudoers`. Since RHEL/CentOS is shipped with that option turned on by default.

Answer (score 3):

If the server has **sudo** installed, you can add yourself to the sudoers file (using the `visudo` command) - you can either allow everything, or just that particular command. Then use `sudo somecommand` to run it with root privileges.

But no matter what method, you will need to login as root at least once - or get someone else to login as root.

**Edit:** sudo has a passwordless option (`NOPASSWD` in sudoers), which doesn't require a tty (if I remember correctly).

Comment: vi /etc/sudoers (EDIT: please use visudo instead)
comment out: #Default requiretty

Answer (score 1):

Get the admin to add "/etc/init.d/tomcat" to the list of commands you can execute w/o password, that way you *can* sudo it without a pty:

```
yourname machinename=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/tomcat
```

There are many other ways to do what you ask, tough.